# Xpath / find all elements which contains attribute

Tags: xpath

I want to find all elements which have an attribute that contains the word: "`aut`".

For example:

```
<div aut20="one" class="model"> Some text </div>
<span aut="two" class="model_1" ng-one="two"> Some text 2 </span>
<a class="three"> some text 2 </a>
```

Then the xpath query result would be `<div>` and `<span>` elements because it has "`aut20`" and "`aut`".

Comment: Did you try searching the site, for example for "[xpath] contains attribute"? There are dozens of exact duplicate questions easily to find.

Comment: @JensErat This is not a duplicate. This question is about the attribute /name/ containing a certain string, not its value.

Comment: Sorry, missread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@*[contains(local-name(),'aut')]/..
```